# Jquery Number counting slowdown animation when target reach

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                            Counter: 123456789
                        }, {
                            duration: 2000,
                            easing: 'easeOutBack',
                            step: function (now) {
                                   $(this).html(parseFloat(now).toFixed(2));
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                            }
});
```

In this code number running same speed till ends. I need the number running speed will slow down when reached the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a variable for speed and incrase this with step. In your exemple is:

```
var speed = 2000;
$(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: 123456789
    }, {
        duration: speed,
        easing: 'easeOutBack',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).html(parseFloat(now).toFixed(2));
            if(counter < 1000){
                speed += 100;
            }   
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
```